# How to set fixed size of cropped images in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

In my application, we are using the crop image but don't want crop area to be resizable. In the image, I don't want those controls under the red circles, it should be fixed at the same size

```
 intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

 intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
 intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
 intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
 intent.putExtra("scale", true);
 intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

[image]

Comment: It's "crop" not corp.

Comment: its corp sir but i need fixed size corp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri)
    {
        // call the standard crop action intent
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri , "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop" , "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data" , true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent , 2);
    }
```

Comment: In this specific case, this Intent action, `com.android.camera.action.CROP`, is supported by the AOSP Camera app. That app does not exist on all devices. Devices lacking this app will not respond to this undocumented Intent action, and your app will crash.