# How to set fixed size mask in android image cropping?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to crop an image from Gallery. When I tried to crop it, a mask is appeared and then I can re-size the mask width and height. But I want the mask can't be re-sizable. User will just have to move the mask only but not able to re-size the mask or rectangle size. So I want the mask size will be fixed. I tried many solution but did not work. Here is the sample code

```
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 4);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

[Sample problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464052/how-to-set-fixed-size-of-cropped-images-in-android). How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think your approach would work on all devices. I would use an open source lib, check out http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Is it worked for you? Which library I can use?