# Cropping issue in Android

Tags: android, image, crop

I am facing same problem like [how to set fixed size of cropped images in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464052/how-to-set-fixed-size-of-cropped-images-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set fixed size of cropped images in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464052/how-to-set-fixed-size-of-cropped-images-in-android)

Comment: i am trying what ani suggested but no luck ... is their any other way to achieve